# Saving 2 related entities where the primary key is generated by a sequence

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have the following database structure:

```
CREATE SEQEUENCE post_id_seq INT START WITH 1;

CREATE TABLE topics 
(
     topic_id INT DEFAULT NEXT VALUE FOR post_id_seq PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE posts 
(
     post_id INT DEFAULT NEXT VALUE FOR post_id_seq PRIMARY KEY, 
     topic_id INT
);
```

Each topic has a "topic post" (identified when the `topic_id = post_id`).

How do I make it so that when I create a topic, I can create the post at the same time and the `topic_id` and `post_id` will be correctly assigned when I run `SaveChanges`?

Something like below:

```
var topic = db.Topics.Add();
var post = db.Posts.Add() { PostId = topic.TopicId, TopicId = topic.TopicId };
db.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

Does topic have a collection of posts? If it does, the following should work:

```
var topic = new Topic()

var postForTopic = new Post();
topic.Posts.Add(postForTopic);

db.Topics.Add(topic);
db.SaveChanges();
```